# etcd error when trying to start service rejected send message

Tags: etcd, calico

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and Im configuring etcd for use with calico, but the service does not work.

This is my etcd.conf file:

```
# vim:set ft=upstart ts=2 et:
description "etcd"
author "etcd maintainers"

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

setuid etcd

env ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd
export ETCD_DATA_DIR

exec /usr/bin/etcd --name="uno" \
--advertise-client-urls="http://172.16.8.241:2379,http://172.16.8.241:4001" \
--listen-client-urls="http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001" \
--listen-peer-urls "http://0.0.0.0:2380" \
--initial-advertise-peer-urls "http://172.16.8.241:2380" \
--initial-cluster-token $(uuidgen) \
--initial-cluster "node1=http://172.16.8.241:2380" \
--initial-cluster-state "new"
```

When I try to start:

```
ikerlan@uno:~$ service etcd start

start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.128" (uid=1000 pid=7374 comm="start etcd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run with `sudo`:

```
sudo service etcd start
```

Then if you got error like:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Rerun after add user `etcd`:

```
sudo adduser etcd
```

Update:

If etcd instance can't start, check the following two things:

1:  your etcd start command is right, in your case, the etcd command can't run as you will get err msg like :

```
etcd: couldn't find local name "uno" in the initial cluster configuration
```

so change your content in `/etc/init/etcd.conf` to :

```
--initial-cluster "uno=http://172.16.8.241:2380" \
```

where your original config is :

```
--initial-cluster "node1=http://172.16.8.241:2380" \
```

2: user `etcd` should have the permission to write to `/var/lib/etcd`

Comment: I can start using sudo, but doesn't really starts, because if I run "sudo service etcd stop", it throws "stop:unknown instance", Or if I restart etcd, it can't stops.

Comment: check the directory '/var/lib/etcd' exists and the binary '/usr/bin/etcd' exists ?

Comment: Yes, they exists, there are /usr/bin/etcd and /usr/bin/etcdctl, and var/lib/etcd too.

Comment: the user 'etcd' exists too ?

Comment: @Asier updated, you can try again, i think it will work :)

Comment: Yes it exists ;S it is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Etcd flags "**name**" and "**initial-cluster**" must be match together.

```
....
    --name="keukenhof" \
    --initial-cluster="keukenhof=http://localhost:2380"
....
```